# Derivative of mean with respect to weights leads to mean always increasing?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, means

I'm having this counterintuitive result that hopefully you fellas can shed me some light.

Imagine a discrete p.d.f with n classes. The mean of this distribution can be written as:

$$ E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i $$

I can ask the question: what would happen if I increase the probability of a certain class, say class $j$. A way to imagine is that is to take the derivative:

$$ \partial_{w_j} E[X]= \partial_{w_j}w_1x_1+\partial_{w_j}w_2x_2+...+\partial_{w_j}w_jx_j+...+\partial_{w_j}w_nx_n
$$
$$\partial_{w_j} E[X] = \partial_{w_j}w_jx_j = x_j $$

So far, so good, but this result seems counterintuitive when you think of in terms of a distribution. Imagine that all $x_i$ are positive. That would imply the mean should always increase even if I'm increasing the probability of the smallest value. How can this be correct?

I tried to correct by assuming trying to add the constrain that $\sum_iw_i=1$,but that essentially becomes cyclical. I can write $w_i(w_j(w_i(w_j.....$

Any ideas how to estimate the effect of increasing the probability of one class on the mean?

Comment: You analysis is almost right, simply write $w_n = 1 - \sum\limits_{i<n} w_i,$ and now take derivatives. This would still need to consider the open set $0<w_i<1$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n.$

Comment: Sorry just to double check. So I should apply this weight formula for all weights after the first. Such that for a 3-class population I get $\partial_{w_1}E = x_1-x_2-x_3$ or only for the last weight (so I would end up with  $\partial_{w_1}E = x_1-x_3$)

Comment: For three weights, you have $E(X) = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + (1-w_1-w_2)x_3,$ then $\partial_{w_1} E(X) = x_1 - x_3,$ and so $E(X)$ will be increasing in $w_1$ if $x_1-x_3>0.$ Note that derivatives only make sense in open sets, and in this case the open set is $\{(w_1,w_2) \mid w_1,w_2>0, 1>w_1+w_2\}.$